Условная структура в f-строке
Имеются условия, от которого будет зависеть значение текстовой строки.
Условий три - значений строки тоже три.
Как мне это впихнуть в f-строку?
Не поймите превратно, но в интернете про f-строки в гайдах пишут максимум, как она круто может значения подставлять.
Про условия я нашел только запись вида:
   f'{"<значение 1>" if <условие> else "<значение 2>"}'  

А можно ли сделать, чтобы три значения (пробовал встраивать еще одну f-строку на место <значение 2> - не получается)?

Не усложняй , посчитай отдельно

Если очень хочется, можно так: f'{x if x>y else y if y>z else z}'

На всякий случай: f'{x}' (где x - какое-то выражение, формирующее строку) полностью аналогично просто x. Для выражений, возвращающих не строку, это будет аналогично str(x). Не оборачивайте в f-строку лишний раз, если можно сделать без нее. Ну и в целом, лучше не злоупотреблять встраиванием сложных выражений в f-строки - вы так только усложняете код (и себе жизнь).

s = 'a'; print(f'{f"{s}"}') - уровень вложения f-строк - 2. Больше можно?

Любую ли программу на Питоне можно записать в виде одной f-строки?

Отдельно не получается - строка имеет три разных значения, они зависят от числового условия.

Прикольный вопрос, если бы был конкурс я бы наверное победила. ;)

Три разных значения - 6 строчек кода.  Максимум 8. Все можно посчитать отдельно.

Stanislav Volodarskiy можно и больше, их просто надо разграничивать разными знаками: ' " """ ""

Попробуйте так
>>> a = 1
>>> 
>>> f'{"2" if a == 2 else "3" if a == 3 else "1"}'
'1'
>>> a = 2
>>> f'{"2" if a == 2 else "3" if a == 3 else "1"}'
'2'
>>> a = 3
>>> f'{"2" if a == 2 else "3" if a == 3 else "1"}'
'3'
>>> 
>>> a = 33
>>> f'{"2" if a == 2 else "3" if a == 3 else "1"}'
'1'
>>> 


Спасибо. Логика записи понятна. Но не сама собой разумеющаяся)

Добавь круглые скобки и логика станет "сама собой разумеющейся"

Магический метод str.__mul__(bool).
Если строка зависит от значения переменной,
то можно решить так:
magic_numbers = (13, 42, 54)

for num in magic_numbers:
    print(''.join(('Это самое'*(num == 13),
                   '"неочевидное"'.__mul__(num == 42),
                   'решение!'*(num == 54))
                  )
        )

output:
Это самое
"неочевидное"
решение!

И тут могут быть тысячи вариантов без ущерба читаемости! ;)
(хотя для 1000 лучше уже использовать dict)

dict только при key == num:
magic_numbers = (_ for _ in (13, "42", 54))

any_strings = {
    13: 'Это решение',
    "42": 'пригодно только —',
    54: '"при оговоренных значениях переменной".'
}

for _ in any_strings:
    print(any_strings[next(magic_numbers)])

output:
Это решение
пригодно только —
"при оговоренных значениях переменной".


в том то и дело, что нужна компактная запись в строку. Я бы итак применил старое доброе условие, но это громоздко

@НикитозСаныч Всё относительно... Например в этом ответе, в цикле while есть пример "компактной" записи в одну строку (логическую).

Ещё вариант с match:
magic_numbers = (_ for _ in ('13', 42, '54'))

for _ in range(4):
    try:
        num = next(magic_numbers)
    except Exception:
        num = _

    match num:
        case '13':
            s = 'Это решение для'
        case 42:
            s = 'оговоренных значений переменной,'
        case '54':
            s = 'но может обработать и —'
        case _:
            s = '"Мы так не договаривались!"'
    print(s)

output:
Это решение для
оговоренных значений переменной,
но может обработать и —
"Мы так не договаривались!"

